# Not able to dispaly large shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, stream-order

I have a large stream vector file (6GB) which contains four files (shp, prj, shx and dbf) all located together. I cannot display in QGIS. I get this error message from QGIS: The shapefile is not valid or it does not contain valid data source.

When we process the same file with GDAL,Ogr2gr and postgis database In all platforms I am getting the same error message as ERROR 4: Invalid offset for entity 11320128

Comment: Shapefiles have maximum size of 2GB. Check the geometry limitations in this link: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/shapefiles/geoprocessing-considerations-for-shapefile-output.htm#:~:text=There%20is%20a%202%20GB,roughly%2070%20million%20point%20features.

Comment: Is there a way that I can use shapefiles greater than 2GB and 70mil points? Can it be converted to geopackage and than be displayed in QGIS?

Comment: It is hard to convert something that is already invalid. Perhaps the same software that created your shapefile can use some other format as output.